# QVariant and qRegisterMetaType question

Tags: linux, qt, qvariant, kdelibs

I have a class Pkg and I need to use it under form of QVariant.

At the end of my Pkg.h I have:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pkg)
```

and this does not give compile errors, but in my main.cpp I have to do:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Pkg>("Pkg");
```

and this does not give errors too, but when I try to create a QVariant(Pkg) I get lots of errors like:

```
In member function 'void MainWindow::FillPackagesList()':  
mainWin.cpp:233: error: 'qRegisterMetaType' isnot a member of 'QMetaType' mainWin.cpp:234: error: no matching function for call to QVariant::QVariant(Pkg&)'                                             

/usr/lib/qt/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:208: note: QVariant::QVariant(Qt::GlobalColor)           
/usr/lib/qt/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:206: note: QVariant::QVariant(const QRegExp&)            
/usr/lib/qt/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:204: note: QVariant::QVariant(const QLocale&)            
/usr/lib/qt/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:203: note: QVariant::QVariant(const QUrl&)               
/usr/lib/qt/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:201: note: QVariant::QVariant(const QRectF&)             
/usr/lib/qt/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:200: note: QVariant::QVariant(const QRect&)
```

and errors over errors again...

Comment: Your question doesn't show the actual error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QVariant constructor won't just take any old type. You need to use [QVariant::setValue()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qvariant.html#setValue) or [qVariantFromValue](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qvariant.html#qVariantFromValue).

Answer (score 0):

ahhhhh solved, many thanks, I've used:

```
 item->data(1,Qt::UserRole).value<Pkg>();
```

item is the QTreeWidgetItem selected in this event:

```
connect(packList,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)), SLOT(setActualPackage(QTreeWidgetItem*)));
```